# C program : Can anyone explain the program ? [ Loop Variables Concept ]

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

can anyone give me a proper explanation of the following code ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 1729;
    int s;
    for(s=0;n;s+=n%10)
        n/=10;
    printf("s:%d\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is " s:10 "

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your program.

Comment: I guess this is a school assignment? Anyway, just consider what for means. It will loop until n is 0, incrementing s with the remainder of a division of n with 10 after the first division by 10 each iteration. Thus calculating 2 + 7 + 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! No, not a school assignment. Just a question I came across in a book I was reading.

Comment: rewriting the loop might help:s=0; while(n/=10) s+=n%10;

Comment: @perh is the value of s calculated before the iteration begins ?

Comment: No, it is set to 0 before the iteration begins, then in each loop it is incremented by the value of the last digit (in base 10) of n, but after n is divided by 10, so it will not include the rightmost digit in the sum.

Comment: Which part **specifically** don't you understand? Everything's standard unobfuscated C. Stepping through it with a debugger, as already suggested, or simply with pen and paper, or in your head, or adding a few print statements, should tell you what's happening.

Comment: @Dukeling What I don't get is this : (s=0;n;s+=n%10) 
Before the loop begins, what is the value of the third loop variable?
(The expression s+=n%10)

Comment: I completely understood what @perh has explained. But it's that I don't understand what the expression s+=n%10 evaluates to before the loop begins ?

Comment: `s = 0` happens before `s += n%10` is done the first time, if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

It sums the digits of n except the last one. 
In your case s = 10 = 1 + 7 + 2

You can see that in the first iteration we divide by 10 and get rid of the digit 9. So n = 172.
Then we keep adding the first-right digit to s until n is zero (we finish to scan the digits)